# How to avoid the repeating of a path in a URL in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an  URL path like

```
http://localhost:8080/laravel/api/data/create/
```

Where `/laravel/api` is the path from the config file

and `/data/create/` is the path which I used in `traits`.

The problem is everytime when I run the function named `connection()`repeatedly,

In Tinker, If I do

```
$data = new Sample;
$data->connection();
http://localhost:8080/laravel/api/data/create/
$data->connection();
http://localhost:8080/laravel/api/data/create/data/create/
$data->connection();
http://localhost:8080/laravel/api/data/create/data/create/data/create/
```

The path `/data/create/` is repeated every time when I perform connection().

It should not be like that, only once the path should be appended, if we perform connection(), like the below.

```
$data->connection();
http://localhost:8080/laravel/api/data/create/
```

I am using a method chaining for appending path .

```
protected $resource[]; //is declared already in the code
protected $url[];
public function addPath()
{
        $old_uri = explode('/', $this->resource['path']);
        $add_uri = explode('/', $this->path);
        $new_uri = array_merge($old_uri, $add_uri);
        $this->resource['path'] = '/'.implode('/', array_filter($new_uri));
        return $this;
    
   }
```

```
public function connection()
{
   $this->addPath()->unparse_url();
   return $url;
}
```

```
private function unparse_url()
    {
        $scheme = isset($this->resource['scheme']) ? $this->resource['scheme'].'://' : '';
        $host = isset($this->resource['host']) ? $this->resource['host'] : '';
        $port = isset($this->resource['port']) ? ':'.$this->resource['port'] : '';
        $user = isset($this->resource['user']) ? $this->resource['user'] : '';
        $pass = isset($this->resource['pass']) ? ':'.$this->resource['pass'] : '';
        $pass = ($user || $pass) ? "$pass@" : '';
        $path = isset($this->resource['path']) ? $this->resource['path'] : '';
        $query = isset($this->resource['query']) ? '?'.$this->resource['query'] : '';
        $fragment = isset($this->resource['fragment']) ? '#'.$this->resource['fragment'] : '';

        $this->url = "$scheme$user$pass$host$port$path$query$fragment";

        return $this;
    }
```

Could someone please help to fix the issue?
Thanks.

Comment: The `addPath()` method should throw a bunch of "undefined variable" errors since neither the `$resource` or `$path` variables are defined in that method.

Comment: The same goes for the variable `$url` in your `connection()`-method. I don't see how this code could return anything at all. Are this the only code you have in those methods, or have you removed stuff? Also, the `addPath()` method supports method chaining, but you're not actually using chaining in the posted code.

Comment: I have a unparse_url() in the connection().

Comment: Please post _all_ relevant code _as it is_. It's good to remove unrelated code from the question, but don't remove directly relevant code.

Comment: Where is `$url` defined? Do you actually mean `return $this->url`?

Comment: `$url` is defined in the code. Could you please to solve this issue?, $this->resource['scheme'], $this->resource['port'] all comes from the config file.

Answer (score 0):

If we disregard from your undefined variables, the issue is that your code appends the path every time you call the `connection()`-method since it calls the `addPath()`-method.

If you only want it to append it once, there are some alternatives.

#### Alternative 1

If you always want the path to be added, you can simple call the `addPath()`-method from the constructor instead.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->addPath()->unparse_url();
}
```

and just have the `connection()`-method like this:

```
public function connection()
{
    return $this->url;
}
```

This would work well as long as you don't need to use the original values of `$this->url` and `$this->resource['path']` for anything since they will be changed when the class is instantiated.

#### Alternative 2

You can set class property as a flag, saying if the path already been added or not. Then you simply check that flag in your `addPath()`-method.

```
// Default value is false, since we haven't added it yet
protected $pathAdded = false;

public function addPath()
{
    if ($this->pathAdded === false) {
        // It's still false so it hasn't been added yet
        
        $old_uri = explode('/', $this->resource['path']);
        $add_uri = explode('/', $this->path);
        $new_uri = array_merge($old_uri, $add_uri);
        $this->resource['path'] = '/'.implode('/', array_filter($new_uri));

        // Set the flag to true so we know it's already been done
        $this->pathAdded = true;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This way, it will only append the path on the first call to that method.

Comment: Thank you sir!, the alternative 1 works fine! I have an another question i have 3 chaining methods in the connection() like `$this->addPath()-> addQuery()->unparse_url();
   return $url;`, But i couldn't get the query for the methods in the URL.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by _"But i couldn't get the query for the methods in the URL"_. However, if you run into some other issue, you should post it as a new question. And if this worked well for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: No sir, It is the same issue I have posted in the code too, Could you please take a look, After adding the alternative 1 to the code , `query` is not getting appended to the URL .Thank you for your support sir !

Comment: No dude. That is _not_ the same question as the original (before your edit 25 mins _after_ I posted the answer). Don't move the goal post! That's pretty disrespectful after I've spent time helping you with the original issue.

Comment: I have a question in the alternative 2, where I already have a `path` set like` protected $path = '/data/create/', Can we add a flag like this  `protected $pathAdded = false;`.?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can add as many class properties you want?

Comment: That means that the original question was answered. Instead of changing the question, you should then accept the answer that helped you and then post a new question for the new issues. This site is meant as a resource for developers, where you can see if others have had the same issue as you and then see the solutions. If you change the question, none of the comments or answers will make sense for future visitors.